# Way Too Many Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying to setup the simplest of simple hibernate applications and for reasons beyond my mediocre way of thinking I cannot get it running. Maven is easy enough - adding dependencies to the build path, updating the project, *blah blah blah yadda yadda yadda*

It started off as a single `ClassNotFoundException` which required a missing dependency. I would import the missing jar and run the app again, only to get *another* `ClassNotFoundException`. Next thing I know I HAVE A TON OF JARS AND NO WORKING APPLICATION

[image]

*Directories have been masked to protect the unfortunate

I've used both Maven and Hibernate in my last project in Eclipse Kepler and it was almost *too* easy, ha! Updating to Luna was a real pain trying to get Maven to run correctly - disabling the Java Compilier Compliance Level just to be able to update the Dynamic Web Module, not to mention manually creating the missing src/main/java and src/test/java folders that are standard with a `maven-archetype-webapp`, the list goes on. I've spent tooooo much time just to get the thing to not fail.

In my last project all I needed to import was:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

That' was it! I was swimming in Session Factories and Updating database tables like it was my job (it is).

This leads me to believe some core functionality is missing from this new project. Perhaps I've overlooked something in the IDE Upgrade. Could almost guarantee its my Build Path. Please Help!

About my project - I'm using:
Eclipse Luna (Kepler was 100x easier to setup with Maven)
Maven Webapp Archetype
JDK-1.7
Hibernate Core 4-3.6

My latest Exception was

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(AnnotationBinder.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at com.boa.ecris.test.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

If this is specific to the javax `persistence-api.jar`, it's already in there!!!

Comment: `persistence-api.jar` doesn't have that missing class. Try adding the `javaee-api.jar`

Comment: Changing ide shouldn't break dependencies - is it the same pom? Also, you will see a lot of jars because Eclipse is showing you all the transient dependencies too.

Comment: I started with the same exact pom, but after I upgraded it must have been lacking some dependencies it had before. Every jar in the list I've had to manually add to the project

Answer (score 2):

Java APIs change over time. You need to find the correct *version* of your dependency (namely the one which contains the version of the API which you want/need to use). Since you told Maven to use version 1.0.2 of `persistance-api`, that's what Maven will do - you might know better.

If the error doesn't go away, then your next step should be the Maven central repo, specifically the "find class for me" search dialog: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Ajavax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Next, you need to understand which dependencies you want in your project and select the correct one from the list. Since Maven doesn't know about your constraints, that is something you have to figure out yourself.

A word of wisdom: A computer doesn't have a brain, bring your own.

Comment: Even though you kind of hurt my feelings, this was a very constructive and helpful answer. I'm by no means a Maven expert but I do learn by example. So thank you

Comment: Yes, I tend to do that :-) OTOH, "*blah blah blah yadda yadda yadda*" makes it hard for me to stay professional ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you have **ClassNotFoundException**, first of all you have to look at your repository site. You can get  **maven repository url** from settings file in .m2 folder. Then you can search your dependency at that site with your **artifact id** and **version**. If your version is not there, you can see some other version and put it instead yours. So you can provide stability at your project without manual adding.

Answer (score 0):

Luna can create the maven project hierarchy too. On the New maven project dialog check the **Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)** checkbox.

Comment: Thanks @babsaai, I just couldn't understand why the webapp archetype didn't initially have those folders